# Map Application : City Guide - Beginner Level

Tags: android, dictionary

I am trying to make an app that shows a city map  in details. Which map should I use ? How can i add markers in my app ? How can i create the map ? Please help guys .

Comment: You need to focus on one specific issue per Stack Overflow question; "how do I do everything?" is not a suitable question.

Comment: Yeah ! I know . I searched the web before posting the question here . I couldn't find the right answer . The main problem for me that i don't have any idea how to create the map . Help please if it wouldn't bother you . Thanks . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about starting in the android developer documentation

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: I went through this . Actually , I have the basics . The problem I am facing is how to create the map . More specifically , If I use google map , how can I add a overlay map in there ? How can I add markers using geopoint in my overlay map .

Comment: the overlay and marker stuff is explained on the same page. Search for HelloItemizedOverlay